# Regular expression in reverse

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++ I want to make an expression that only keeps the email addresses of that text and that removes everything else.

Imagine that we have the following text:

> `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <micorreo0@gmail.com>consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ac risus molestie, laoreet ligula vitae, tincidunt risus.<micorreo1@gmail.com> Aliquam ut felis efficitur, iaculis nunc in, feugiat dui.<micorreo2@gmail.com> Etiam sodales ligula tellus, id vehicula augue aliquet eu. Nulla blandit maximus lectus, quis consequat metus vulputate suscipit. Duis finibus lorem justo, non sollicitudin urna aliquet a. Sed at ligula justo. Nam est ex, suscipit in facilisis nec, rutrum vitae urna<micorreo3@gmail.com>.`

The mails will always go between the `<>` signs.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[^<]*(<[^>]+>)[^<]*`
- Replace with: `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[^<]*   : 0 or more any character that is not <
(       : begin capture group
  <     : literally <
  [^>]+ : 1 or more any character that is not >
  >     : literally >
)       : end group
[^<]*   : 0 or more any character that is not <
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1        : group 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed.
A greeting.